# Firejail --private can't launch .sh file in home directory

Tags: ubuntu, security, firejail

I can create a bash script, then launch it using firejail with the private option :

```
phil@GLaDOS:~$ echo "echo success" > /media/phil/Stockage/firejailtest.sh; chmod +x /media/phil/Stockage/firejailtest.sh 
phil@GLaDOS:~$ firejail --noprofile --private /media/phil/Stockage/firejailtest.sh 
Parent pid 117110, child pid 117111
Child process initialized in 8.67 ms
success

Parent is shutting down, bye...
```

Which works fine.

However, if my script is in my home directory, or any folder in the home directory, the above will fail :

```
phil@GLaDOS:~$ echo "echo success" > /home/phil/firejailtest.sh; chmod +x /home/phil/firejailtest.sh 
phil@GLaDOS:~$ firejail --noprofile --private /home/phil/firejailtest.sh 
Parent pid 117357, child pid 117358
Child process initialized in 8.73 ms
/bin/bash: ligne 1: /home/phil/firejailtest.sh: No such file or directory

Parent is shutting down, bye...
```

How do I launch a script or program within my home directory, with firejail, using "private" to ensure no modification is made to any of my files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man firejail`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/firejail.1.html):

> [`--private`](https://manpages.debian.org/firejail/firejail.1#private)
>
> Mount new `/root` and `/home/user` directories in temporary filesystems.
> All modifications are discarded when the sandbox is closed.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ firejail --private firefox
> ```

> [`--private-home=file,directory`](https://manpages.debian.org/firejail/firejail.1#private_home=file,directory)
>
> Build a new user home in a temporary filesystem, and copy the files
> and directories in the list in the new home. The files and directories
> in the list must be expressed as relative to the current user's home
> directory. All modifications are discarded when the sandbox is closed.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> $ firejail --private-home=.mozilla firefox
> ```

The options for all intents and purposes are doing the same. So you could use instead:

```
firejail --noprofile --private-home=firejailtest.sh /home/phil/firejailtest.sh
```

You can verify that the only difference is this additional file:

```
firejail --noprofile --private find /home/phil
```

versus:

```
firejail --noprofile --private-home=firejailtest.sh find /home/phil
```

---

Nitpicking: the two options are doing *almost* the same but not exactly (hence: "for all intents and purposes" above) as can be seen with:

```
 firejail --noprofile --private cat /proc/self/mountinfo
```

versus:

```
 firejail --noprofile --private-home=firejailtest.sh cat /proc/self/mountinfo
```

Comment: As I understand it: under private, the location of the script itself is no more accessible, so you have to move the script to the new home before launching it. If however you're under /media, the location is always accessible even with the private option

Comment: Yes (except it's a copy (in a tmpfs) not a move).